# Output clause in delete statement returns an error when using a table alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table Test (a varchar(11));

create table Test2 (a varchar(11));

insert into Test values('a'),('b'),('c');
```

This one works just fine

```
delete from Test output deleted.a into Test2(a)
```

However this one doesn't work

```
delete t from Test t output deleted.a into Test2(a)
```

> Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.

I want to be able to use a table alias there since the actual query is something like this:

```
DELETE t 
FROM Test t 
LEFT JOIN blah blah
WHERE blah blah
OUTPUT DELETED.a INTO Test2(a)
```

Comment: I believe you want `delete t output deleted.a into Test2(a) from Test t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you want is `DELETE <alias> OUTPUT ... FROM ...`:

```sql
DELETE T
OUTPUT deleted.a INTO dbo.Test2(a)
FROM dbo.Test T;
```

So, for your `LEFT JOIN` example, it would be:

```sql
DELETE t 
OUTPUT DELETED.a
INTO Test2(a)
FROM dbo.Test t 
     LEFT JOIN dbo.blah b on t.a = b.b --A lEFT JOIN on a simple DELETE seems odd mind
WHERE t.c = 2;
```

Comment: And just for confusion, if reading the docs you might end up with `DELETE FROM T
OUTPUT deleted.a INTO dbo.Test2(a)
FROM dbo.Test T;` i.e. double `FROM` (confused me anyway lol).

Comment: [Example F](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#f-using-output-into-with-from_table_name-in-a-delete-statement) has a good demonstration, @DaleK . It doesn't use an alias, but all the syntax the OP wants is there. The way to read it is more `DELETE [Table Name | Table Alias] FROM <Table Name> [[AS] Table Alias]`. `DELETE FROM TableName` is omitting the optional `Table Name | Table Alias` after `DELETE`. You *could* write it as `DELETE TableName FROM TableName;` if you *really* wanted.

Comment: Even more confusing - well sort of - it uses the full table name twice as far as the delete is concerned, but then uses the alias for the join... hmmm... oh well, not the most common use case.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like `DELETE TableName FROM TableName AS TN;` should error or give the *wrong* behaviour, @DaleK . But that's a different discussion. :)